# How to connect host database and remote database for replication? ORA-04052; ORA-00604; ORA-12154; ORA-06512

Tags: database, oracle, networking

I am currently trying to make a multi-master replication in Oracle Database 11g between the database AR421 on my host computer (Win10x64) and the database STUD421 on my guest (Win7x86 virtual machine), but I cannot make them communicate.

I turned off the Firewall; I configured my virtual machine to use guest permissions and 2 network adapters: 1 NAT and another Host-only with static IP (so that I can ping from host to guest and vice versa); I started all Oracle-related services from Control Panel and set them to automatic.

In Oracle SQLDeveloper I created a schema/user for each database, both named ARip and both having a table named STUDENT with 1 identical row (no data inside).

The following code has been written in SQLPlus:

*HOST and GUEST:

```
CREATE USER REPMM IDENTIFIED BY REPMM DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP;
EXEC DBMS_REPCAT_ADMIN.GRANT_ADMIN_ANY_SCHEMA('REPMM');
EXEC DBMS_DEFER_SYS.REGISTER_PROPAGATOR('REPMM');
EXEC DBMS_REPCAT_ADMIN.REGISTER_USER_REPGROUP (USERNAME => 'REPMM', PRIVILEGE_TYPE => 'RECEIVER', LIST_OF_GNAMES => NULL);
```

*HOST:

```
CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK STUD421 USING 'STUD';
CONN REPMM/REPMM
CREATE DATABASE LINK STUD421 CONNECT TO REPMM IDENTIFIED BY REPMM USING 'STUD';
```

*GUEST:

```
CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK AR421 USING 'AR';
CONN REPMM/REPMM
CREATE DATABASE LINK AR421 CONNECT TO REPMM IDENTIFIED BY REPMM USING 'AR';
```

*HOST:

```
EXEC DBMS_REPCAT.CREATE_MASTER_REPGROUP('REPLICATION');
EXEC DBMS_REPCAT.CREATE_MASTER_REPOBJECT('ARip', 'STUDENT', 'TABLE', -
- GNAME=>'REPLICATION');

EXEC DBMS_REPCAT.ADD_MASTER_DATABASE (GNAME=> 'REPLICATION', MASTER=>'STUD421', USE_EXISTING_OBJECTS => TRUE,COPY_ROWS=> FALSE, PROPAGATION_MODE=> 'ASYNCHRONOUS');
```

At the last line of code I encountered the following errors:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04052: error occurred when looking up remote object REPMM.SYS@STUD421
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 2
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_REPCAT_UTL", line 4280
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_REPCAT_MAS", line 2158
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_REPCAT", line 146
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Connect identifiers are present in a file called tnsnames.ora .My file (on host) has the following content:

```
LISTENER_AR421 = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1522))

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1522)) ) (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = CLRExtProc) (PRESENTATION = RO) ) ) 

AR421 = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1522)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = AR421) ) )
```

Comment: (I've retagged this so that Oracle11g is the primary tag - the other one does not have many followers, and VirtualBox became the primary tag instead).

Comment: Thanks for that! This is my first question here, so I appreciate any help.

Comment: No worries. I would guess the main error is "TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified" and the error above that is just the error rippling up the call stack. Have you been able to identify which "connect identifier" it is having trouble with?

Comment: OK. I haven't touched a `tnsnames.ora` file for about 15 years, so I won't be much help here. I assume it helps Oracle convert database names into IP addresses to connect to. If that is so, are you able to check that they are all reachable manually?

Comment: I have only one database on the host, named AR421, and I don't know how to see if it is reachable except creating connections for it in sqldeveloper.

Comment: You mentioned a remote database also - is it trying to resolve something there?

Comment: I think so. The last line of code theoretically includes the remote database into the replication group.

Comment: Do you need a `tnsnames.ora` on the remote as well?

Comment: Yes. The remote has the file with its own listener and connect identifier.